# URL to a file on my computer

Tags: url, hyperlink

how to create a url to a file on my computer that can be downloadable from everywhere something like:

```
http://111.111.11.11:80\Users\MYDESKTOP\Desktop/file.zip
or
https://111.111.11.11:443\Users\MYDESKTOP\Desktop/file.zip
or
ftp.111.111.11.11:21\Users\MYDESKTOP\Desktop/file.zip
```

is it possible?

Comment: You'd need to set up a web or ftp (or some other service that can serve files over the network) server application and then make the file accessible to it.

Comment: @CollinD in html form input=file i guess it generate something like the url above